# Recursively calculate columns and add to Spark Dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and Apache Spark. I am trying to calculate mean and standard deviation for a few columns in a Spark dataframe and append the result to the source dataframe. I am trying to do this recursively. Following is my function.

```
def get_meanstd_data(mergedDF: DataFrame, grpByList: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {

val normFactors = Iterator("factor_1", "factor_2", "factor_3", "factor_4")

def meanStdCalc(df: DataFrame, column: String): DataFrame = {
  val meanDF = df.select("column_1", column).groupBy(grpByList.head, grpByList.tail: _*).
    agg(mean(column).as("mean_" + column))
  val stdDF = df.select("column_1", column).groupBy(grpByList.head, grpByList.tail: _*).
    agg(stddev_pop(column).as("stddev_" + column))
  val finalDF = meanDF.join(stdDF, usingColumns = grpByList, joinType = "left")
  finalDF
}

def recursorFunc(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  @tailrec
  def recursorHelper(acc: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    if (!normFactors.hasNext) acc
    else recursorHelper(meanStdCalc(acc, normFactors.next()))
  }
  recursorHelper(df)
}
val finalDF = recursorFunc(mergedDF)
finalDF
```

}

But when I call the function, the resulting dataframe only contains mean and standard deviation of "factor_4". How do I get a dataframe with the mean and standard deviation of all factors appended to the original dataframe?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you post input & output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't need to use a custom recursive method and you could use `fold`.
Something like creating `normFactors` as `List` and using `foldLeft`:

```scala
val normFactors = Iterator("factor_1", "factor_2", "factor_3", "factor_4")

normFactors.foldLeft(mergedDF)((df, column) => meanStdCalc(df, column))
```

`foldLeft` allows you to use the `DataFrame` as an accumulator

Comment: foldLeft works like a gem. Thank you! I used the following link for reference.
http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-8-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-collection-functions/scala-foldleft-example/